# pygame.mixer.music: Отследить конец музыки, чтобы запустить следующий файл

Tags: python, pygame

Есть программа которая воспроизводит звук с помощью pygame . Когда кончается музыки в функции music2(), нужно что бы запускалась музыки из music2(), но как это сделать? 
Код программы:

```
import pygame

def music():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
def music2():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('bsound.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

music()
```

Comment: @jfs Если так :     if pygame.mixer.music.queue('bsound.mp3'):
        music() , то не работает

Comment: @jfs Данный код:def music2():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('bsound.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    pygame.mixer.music.queue('music.mp3')

music2()  не воспроизводит музыку  после окончания bsound.mp3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы пару mp3 файла проиграть один за другим, в рамках `pygame.mixer.music`, можно использовать [`queue()` функцию](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.queue):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
"""Usage: play <first> <second>"""
import sys
import pygame  # apt install python-pygame

STOPPED_PLAYING = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
first, second = sys.argv[1:]
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(STOPPED_PLAYING)
pygame.mixer.music.load(first)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.mixer.music.queue(second)
for _ in range(2):  # until all files are stopped playing
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    assert event.type == STOPPED_PLAYING
pygame.quit()
```